# How to find the largest elements in a 3-D matrix with it's location?

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am working on 3-D matrices, I wanted to know how to find the location of the largest elements in the Matrices.

```
m = np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2], 
               [ 3,  4,  5],  
               [ 6,  7,  8]],

              [[ 9, 10, 11],
               [12, 13, 14],
               [15, 16, 17]],

              [[18, 19, 20],
               [21, 22, 23],
               [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: iterate trough entire matrix, and equate it to `max(m)` or to `np.max(m)`

Comment: @BlueRineS one does not simply iterate over a numpy array. There are numpy functions for everything. They are much faster and legible than any iteration.

Comment: @eumiro My answer is the naive approach (that's why it's a comment and not a real answer), but I'm guessing those pythonic numpy functions use some sort of iterative search method under the hood anyways..

Answer (score 1):

use amax  to find largest and where to find index:

```
i,j,k = np.where(m == np.amax(m))
```

i,j,k for 3 indexes of  3D array